# Why isn't my dateFormat working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datefilter

I have the following code in AngularJS 1.3.10:

```
ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
    console.log(modelValue)
    var temp = dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log(temp);
    return temp;
});
```

The result returned is still in the full date format of

```
Fri Feb 27 2015 14:05:20 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

instead of

```
2014-02-27
```

Here is a plunker that shows the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pOKtD5hScXsPMHFAeglC?p=preview

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with

```
var temp = dateFilter(new Date(modelValue), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

(That said, I don't really know enough about formatters to know if this is a proper solution or if you should be doing something else differently.)

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is because there is a default formatter that converts its argument to a string, and Angular executes the formatters in *reverse order*. Because you inserted your formatter at the front, the default formatter had already converted the model value into a string before you saw it. So alternatively you could change `unshift` to `push`, or just replace the entire `$formatters` array with an array containing just your function, and those would both work equivalently. I'm not entirely sure what side effects doing so would have.

Comment: Curious why my model is defined as a Date, but it's coming into the directive as a string.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out exactly how this works. It does turn out there is a default formatter there that converts its argument to a string, but I'm still a bit baffled by the sequence of events.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your model value inside `Date Object`. Because in order to use angular date filter you need to pass a Date Javascript Object.

```
dateFilter(new Date(modelValue), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Here is your http://plnkr.co/edit/Jdms8NOtdMQ83KLb1X0D working